# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) happens by running with breakpoint

Tags: xcode, swift

I get the following error report every time I run app with a breakpoint by cmd+R.
But without breakpoint it doesn't happen.

The following is only extract, because it's too long.

```
Process:               Xcode [1979]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.2 (7718)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7718000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812404257
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1979]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-05-20 21:23:33.314 +0900
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        DF41C897-AEB0-55A8-F81A-A5CFBC23D66C


Time Awake Since Boot: 2100 seconds

Crashed Thread:        26

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010acf8000-000000010acf9000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D2105

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95f9d4de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95f9c64f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88976eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8897637b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88975bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b92756f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b9272ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b92712b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a50a9bb _DPSNextEvent + 978
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a509f68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010b453aaa -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a4ffbf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a47c354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
```

My environment is

Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B18, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6

Comment: Crashed Thread:        26 - what is he doing over there that you're not telling us? :-) Paste in the relevant stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Double click your executable in the “Executables” in XCode

-Open “Arguments” tab

-In “Variables to be set in the environment” (that’s the list at the bottom, be careful which one you edit) click the “+” button and for name of the variable enter “NSZombieEnabled” and for value “YES”